# What makes an album "deluxe"?

Tags: terminology, album

right to the point:

What makes an album as a "deluxe version"? People may notice that they usually have some bonus tracks. But, what makes them deluxe other than that?

Comment: It could be literally anything that the record company wants the consumer to believe provides added value - bonus tracks, extra remix CD or live DVD, limited edition artwork booklet... thicker vinyl / gold CD... blessed by the Pope... It's just a marketing term, similar to 'Special Edition', 'Collector's Edition', etc.

Comment: @topomorto - That's the actual answer, so you should make it one...

Comment: @ChrisSunami done. I was thinking it was a slightly simple question to warrant an actual answer, but then this is a cross-generation and international site, so maybe that was an unfair thought.

Comment: OK nearly 5 years have passed since the last comment, and now streaming music is much more popular I would argue Deluxe is an oxymoron. Deluxe=crap added to spoil the original album and make skipping of tracks more necessary. (Similar to DVD 'extras' in the olden days.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really just a marketing term, similar to 'Special Edition', 'Collector's Edition', and so on. It could potentially be anything that the record company wants the consumer to believe provides added value. An extra remix CD or live DVD, limited edition artwork booklet... thicker vinyl / gold CD... or, as The Smiths tell us in  [*Paint A Vulgar Picture*](http://www.metrolyrics.com/paint-a-vulgar-picture-lyrics-the-smiths.html): *Double-pack with a photograph, Extra track, and a tacky badge...*

Comment: I actually didn't steal the Morrissey quote from you... I just went away from the computer for 15 minutes, and saw your answer after I posted mine... Funny coincidence.

Comment: @Magnilex A case of "Stop Me If You Think You've Heard This One Before"... :)

Answer (score 8):

Wikipdia has a general page called [Special Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_edition#Music), which also contains a good definition of Deluxe Editions.

> In terms of musical albums, the term "deluxe edition" refers to a re-release of an album, generally a sufficient period after the initial release, featuring extra content related to the album. This often includes some or all of the following: extra tracks; demo recordings of album tracks; live recordings of album tracks; alternate takes, mixes, or edits of album tracks; B-sides from album singles that did not appear on the album; DVD content, including music videos. These editions are commonly repackaged, with the new content on a second disc and many feature additional liner notes.
>
> Also, some albums are initially released in two editions, a regular retail version and a "special" or "limited" version in distinctive packaging and often including extras such as a second disc, a video DVD, or liner notes expanded into a hardback book. Generally, the special package is only produced for the first pressing or a set number of copies - some are limited to only being sold at one chain of retailers. It is important to distinguish this from an expanded re-release, since those are generally available widely and for a long period of time.

So, a Deluxe Edition is typically, but not always, released after the origninal album. Also, it most probably features some extra material to make people buy it.

Additionally, the page has the following definition:

> The terms special edition, limited edition, and variants such as deluxe edition, collector's edition or expanded edition, are used as a marketing incentive for various kinds of products, originally published products related to the arts, such as books, prints, video games or recorded music and films, but now including cars, fine wine, and whisky, among other products.

So, it is definitely a marketing "trick" as well. The record companies know that record buyers are interested in extra material, and are willing to pay for it.

Finally, I just cannot resist [quoting Morrissey](http://genius.com/1873007/The-smiths-paint-a-vulgar-picture/Re-issue-re-package-re-package-re-evaluate-the-songs-double-pack-with-a-photograph-extra-track-and-a-tacky-badge) here:

> Re-issue! Re-package! Re-package!
> Re-evaluate the songs
> Double-pack with a photograph
> Extra track (and a tacky badge)

Answer (score -2):

Posted by Ferrari_Salami `✔️ Verified Community Helper`

In simple words, a deluxe edition is a second edition of an album made by an artist. They include a few extras, and are usually for marketing. They are often made by the artist if they don't make as much money or profit as they would have liked, they will remake the album to get more hits and profit, similar to re-uploading or re-posting a social media `(i.e. Instagram)` post to get more views and likes.

So to summarise: a deluxe album is a repost of an original album from an artist with a few added extras to help make extra profit from listeners. A deluxe album is often made by artists when they haven't reached their target profit `(or have not hit their number of plays goal)`.

I hope this helps!
If you have any questions at all, feel free reply in the thread.
Thanks for using StackExchange!

Written by Ferrari_Salami `✔️ Verified Community Helper`

Comment: The amount of self-advertising - likely to be removed - and the use of code-style formatting indicates, that you could benefit from re-visiting the help section.